# Image height cutoff in Outlook 2007/2010 (well below max height)

Tags: outlook, html-email, zurb-ink

I have an image in an HTML email template where the height is being cutoff. I'm using the Zurb Ink email framework. The setup is two images that are supposed to stack on top of each other. From what I can tell the image is being cutoff at 19px in height, while it's actual height is 47px;

I'm using Email on Acid to preview the email. The CSS is being inlined before the email is sent using `premailer`.

The 2nd image displays fine.

Here's the relevant code and screenshots.

**HTML**

```
<table class="row banner">
  <tr>
    <td class="wrapper last">
      <table class="four columns">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img class="hide-for-small" src="url-to-image.jpg" width="179" height="47" style="width:179px; height:47px; line-height:47px;" />
            <br/>
            <img src="url-to-image.jpg" width="179" height="63" style="width:179px; height:63px; line-height:63px;" />
          </td>
          <td class="expander"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

**Inlined CSS** - after all the CSS is compiled and inlined.

```
td {
  word-break: break-word; 
  -webkit-hyphens: auto; 
  -moz-hyphens: auto; 
  hyphens: auto; 
  border-collapse: collapse !important; 
  vertical-align: top; 
  text-align: left; 
  color: #222222; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  line-height: 19px; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0px 0px 10px;
}

img {
  width: 179px; 
  height: 47px; 
  line-height: 47px;
  outline: none; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
  max-width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  clear: both; 
  display: block;
```

**Screenshots**

Outlook 2007/2010
[image]

Normal Email Clients
[image]

I've tried adding `height`, `style="height"` and `line-height` attributes to force the height but to no luck so far.

Comment: Can you provide the Screenshots? I don't see them...

Comment: @CalvT - I updated the question with screenshots and additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats don't work in Outlook. What you want is to use `<td align="left|right|center">` instead. You should use `td`'s `valign` and `height` attributes too.

The width bit could be causing the problem too, you should set the width of the image via the `width` attribute and then set the style `max-width:100%` inline to accomplish what you want and keep it cross-client.

Comment: I added `align:left` and `valign:top` to the `td` element but am still seeing the issue. One clue, the pink image (the one being cutoff) has a height of 19px, which is the `line-height` of the enclosing `td`. Could the `<br/>` tag being causing the top image to be cutoff at the `line-height`?

Comment: i think you're on the right track. your images are set to `display:block` so there's no need for that `<br/>`

Comment: Without the `<br/>` in there the images were displaying inline. Maybe I need to adjust the column width to force the images to wrap without a `<br/>`, or make the image width fit the width of the column.

Comment: The solution turned out to be a combination of removing `float:left`, removing the `<br/>` and making the image width fill the table column.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `mso-line-height-rule: at-least` on the TD that the image sits in. I've found issues with MSO email clients where it would crop images to the line-height unless this option is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with the height being cut off in Outlook only.  I solved this by removing the custom class(es) on my image.